# Image Not Uploading - but PHP says it is?

Tags: php, image

I have a few different upload scripts and when I try each of them, they are always "successful" - none of the upload errors are returned and a "your image has uploaded" message comes up.

But when I check the web directory..... no image.

What am I missing?

I'm using GoDaddy as a host right now...

Comment: This is probably because… um… something went wrong in your script but it erroneously reported a success. I hope this answer was satisfactory. Have a nice day, sir.

Comment: Can you show some code? Maybe a `var_dump($_FILES)` as well?

Comment: WillHerndon, SO is a website with technicians, not with clear-sighted people. Please show us the code and maybe we can help you...

Comment: Which part of the code is helpful.... the .php file with the upload, the php class?

Comment: The part that has to do with saving the upload and outputting a success/error message.

Comment: My guess for possible error. Check that your file writing from tmp to your desired path is correctly working. Check your destination path with realpath() function, if the path is translating correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and `display_errors = On` in php.ini, and at least, you'll see what's wrong there..